# How to reduce space between an image and a photo slideshow?

Tags: html, css

So I have an image and a slideshow on my website.

Image can be viewed here:

[image]

As you can see, there is a space between the grass logo and the slideshow.  Is there anyway to get rid of that space? (space has a yellow arrow between the two objects)

HTML

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css" />
<STYLE>
<!--
A{text-decoration:none}
-->
</STYLE>
</head>

<title>Webcleats, LLC - Traction on the Web</title>

<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF"> 

<center><h2><a href="index.html" style="color: #000000">Home</a> &nbsp; <a href="about.html" style="color: #000000">About Us</a> &nbsp; <a href="services.html" style="color: #000000">Services</a> &nbsp; <a href="customers.html" style="color: #000000">Customers</a> &nbsp; <a href="contact.html" style="color: #000000">Contact Us</a></a></center></h2>

<h1> <center><a href="index.html" target="_blank"> <img src="webcleats_logo.tiff" /></a></center> </h1>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <!-- Start WOWSlider.com HEAD section -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="engine1/style.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="engine1/jquery.js"></script>
    <!-- End WOWSlider.com HEAD section -->
</head>
<body style="background-color:#d7d7d7">
    <!-- Start WOWSlider.com BODY section -->
    <div id="wowslider-container1">
    <div class="ws_images"><ul>
<li><img src="data1/images/newest.001.jpg" alt="newest.001" title="" id="wows1_0"/></li>
<li><img src="data1/images/district_lines.002.jpg" alt="district_lines.002" title="" id="wows1_1"/></li>
<li><img src="data1/images/see_me.jpg" alt="see_me" title="" id="wows1_2"/></li>
</ul></div>
<div class="ws_bullets"><div>
<a href="#" title="newest.001"><img src="data1/tooltips/newest.001.jpg" alt="newest.001"/>1</a>
<a href="#" title="district_lines.002"><img src="data1/tooltips/district_lines.002.jpg" alt="district_lines.002"/>2</a>
<a href="#" title="Hang out with me!"><img src="data1/tooltips/see_me.jpg" alt="see_me"/>3</a>
</div></div>
    <div class="ws_shadow"></div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="engine1/wowslider.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="engine1/script.js"></script>
    <!-- End WOWSlider.com BODY section -->
</body>
</html>
```

And CSS (doesn't have a lot on it at the moment, I am new to CSS)

```
h1 {
    margin:5spx;
}
#title span {
    font-size: 4em;
    color: #c13636;
    line-height: 0.9em
}
#sidebar .links a:hover {
    color:"white";
}

#webcleats {
    margin: 5px 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you post your code? You'll need to use `margin-bottom` or `margin-top` depending on which element you want to style.

Comment: and your stylesheet as well please?

Comment: You omitted the part with the logo image and only provided us with the slider part. To remove the space between them, we might need both pieces.

Comment: The logo image is in the h1.

Comment: @ZachPawlowski: The answer below pretty much answers your question, although your code has a lot of nasties in it. You've got two sets of `<head>` tags, if you're thinking of `<header>` element new to HTML5, then use that because readable content shouldn't be placed in `<head>`. I don't understand why you're putting your logo image inside of `<h1>` tags; is it because you're trying to emphasize it as the header content, or because you're trying to improve accessibility? (Consider using `<img src="logo.png" alt="my logo image">` instead.) And you've got two sets of `<body>` tags as well.

Answer (score 0):

This ought to fix you up, although it's hard to tell from your code whether the problem is the `<H1>` or the `<UL>`. Try one or the other to determine the offender.

```
h1,
h1 img {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

#wowslider-container1 ul,
#wowslider-container1 ul li {
    margin-top: 0;
    padding-top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

simple,

add this to your header image css :

```
margin-bottom:0px;
```

and add css for your wow slider div so it looks like this:

```
#wowslider-container1 {

    width[enter your width];
    height:[enter your height];
    margin-top:0px;
    padding-top:0px;
}
```

and replace [enter your width/height] with whatever values you want them to be.